# Pass arguments or containing object to jQuery UI draggable events

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-events

Say I have following code:

```
var mainObj = {
  area: $("#elementsArea"),
  elements: [],

  addElement: function (x, y) {
    var newElement = $('<div class="element"></div>');
    newElement.css("top", y);
    newElement.css("left", x);
    newElement.appendTo(this.area);
    this.elements.push( { id: this.elements.length, x: x, y: y } );
    newElement.dragabble({
      stop: function () {
        // What to do here?
      }
    });
  },

  updateElement: function ( element_id, x, y ) {
    // Find element in this.elements table table and update x, y
  },

  setup: function () {
    this.area.bind('click', this, function (e) {
      e.data.addElement( e.offsetX, e.offsetY );
    });
  }
}

$(document).ready( function () { mainObj.setup() } );
```

HTML, and CSS are irrelevant, other attributes and functions too. What I want to do is to somehow pass new position after draggable event stops to the `updateElement` method, so I can update object in *elements* table, similar to what I did with *click* event.

How can I do it, or did I make something bad with code design?

Comment: You've misspelt `draggable` in your `addElement` function. You're missing a 'g' and there's an additional 'b'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stop function has two parameters, I think you can reach from them those information what you need for update, something like this:
http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-stop

```
newElement.dragabble({
    stop: function (event, ui) {
        var element_id = ui.helper.attr('id');// or get id as you want
        // ui.position or ui.offset try what you need
        this.updateElement(element_id, ui.position.top, ui.position.left);
    }
});
```

(haven't tested just an idea schema)

tested and improved version:

```
addElement: function (x, y) {
    var self = this;// self is an alias for this
    var id = 'id_' + this.elements.length;// create unique ID
    var newElement = $('<div class="element"></div>');
    newElement.css("top", y);
    newElement.css("left", x);
    newElement.attr('id', id);//add ID for element
    newElement.appendTo(this.area);
    this.elements.push( { id: id, x: x, y: y } );
    newElement.dragabble({
       stop: function () {
          var element_id = ui.helper.attr('id');
          // ui.position or ui.offset try what you need
          self.updateElement(element_id, ui.position.top, ui.position.left);
        }
    });
},
```

Comment: Nope. Note that "this" is not "mainObj" anymore, as you pass an object to draggable function (so this reffers to the object you pass as an argument). I tried to add "parentThis: this", before stop method, but didn't work as well.

So when you write:
this.updateElement(element_id, ui.position.top, ui.position.left);

it returns undefined method.

Comment: In the first code schema I just indicated how can you reach needed information within stop method, you have to decide how you would like to use them. (see second block for example...)

Comment: OK, in the updated version of you code, the second line was what I was looking for.

Comment: The second line in the improved block is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 1):

In the `stop` event, you need to call `updateElement` on `mainObj` and pass the current element's `id`, `x` and `y` values. You can query the `ui` object to get the required values.

Your updated `addElement` function:

```
addElement: function(x, y) {
  var newElement = $('<div class="element"></div>');
  newElement.css("top", y);
  newElement.css("left", x);
  newElement.attr('id', elemId);
  elemId++;
  newElement.appendTo(this.area);
  this.elements.push({
    id: this.elements.length,
    x: x,
    y: y
  });
  newElement.draggable({
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      //Call updateElement on mainObj.
      mainObj.updateElement(ui.helper[0].id, ui.position.left, ui.position.top);
    }
  });
}
```

**[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/yassarikhan786/4a325k1c/)** that updates a `span` with the `id`, `x` and `y` positions of the dragged element.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve my problem was colde like that

```
new_el.bind('drag', this, function ( e, ui ) {
  e.data.updateElementCoordinates( $(this).attr("element-id"), $(this).css("left"), $(this).css("top") );
});
```

That way we can acces mainObj properties from within the callback, the same way you would do that with f. eg. "click" event.